# Verbose exception catch clauses

Tags: java, exception

**Background**
I have a case where my logic requires surround with try/catch, I have a lots of catch clauses, which makes my code a bit ugly. What I do in catch clause is only log the error using log4j.
**Question**
Is it ok to use one catch clause with parent exception type instead of bunch of catch clauses?
Instead of this:

```
try{
        //some statements
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
} catch (CertificateException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
} catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
} catch (NoPropertyFoundException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
}
```

using :

```
try{

    //some statements
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
}
```

Which one is better?

Comment: If you intend to catch all the subclasses of a given exception class then it's perfectly reasonable to use that (super) class.  It's not a good idea to catch Exception, though, even if you rethrow the ones that aren't "keepers" -- it gets messy real fast.  (It would be nice if Java had more of a hierarchy to exceptions, to facilitate catching groups of them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to use one catch clause with parent exception type instead of bunch of catch clauses?

Hunter has provided the correct solution for Java 7 and later.

---

For Java 6 and earlier, it depends on the parent exception that you choose.  Exceptions like `Throwable`, `Exception` and `RuntimeException` are far too general.  If you catch these, you can end up accidentally catching (and then mishandling) exceptions that you should allow to propagate.  For example, your code would catch  `NullPointerException` that you should probably not attempt to recover from ... like that.

The first version is more correct / more robust than the second version, and that better even if it looks ugly.

---

Of course, the real answer depends on what happens *after* you have caught and logged the exception.  If what happens next is appropriate for *all* exceptions, then the second version is (arguably) preferable.  For instance, it could be appropriate to catch all exceptions, log them and then call `System.exit(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

When catch exceptions I usually find that more specific is better, that being said typing out all of those different blocks that do the same thing can get really annoying. Thankfully in the Java 7 release a try-catch notation was added where you can specific *multiple* exceptions for a single block:

```
try{
        //some statements
} catch (KeyStoreException         |
         CertificateException      |
         NoSuchAlgorithmException  |
         FileNotFoundException     |
         IOException               |
         UnrecoverableKeyException |
         NoPropertyFoundException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
}
```

This sounds like what you are looking for, but there is more detailed information in the Oracle docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html